# BigQuery: IN a temporary table

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a long SQL query looking like this:

```sql
SELECT AVG(total_sum) AS avg_total_sum, COUNT(*) AS cnt
FROM (
  SELECT order_id, ...
  FROM `project.dataset.orders`
  WHERE order_id NOT IN (
    SELECT order_id
    FROM `project.dataset.orders`
    CROSS JOIN UNNEST(gifts) AS gifts
    WHERE ...
  )
)
```

And this works well, but I'd like to simplify the code by splitting it in temporary tables, like this:

```sql
WITH t_ids AS (
  SELECT order_id
  FROM `project.dataset.orders`
  CROSS JOIN UNNEST(gift_details) AS gift_details
  WHERE ...
)

SELECT AVG(total_sum) AS avg_total_sum, COUNT(*) AS cnt
FROM (
  SELECT order_id, ...
  FROM `project.dataset.orders`
  WHERE order_id NOT IN t_ids
)
```

But it leads to the following error:

> Syntax error: Expected "(" or keyword UNNEST but got identifier "t_ids"

I tried to add parentheses, `UNNEST`, but it seems to be not working with temp table. How the problem can be solved?

Answer (score 1):

you can try like below

```
WITH t_ids AS (
    SELECT order_id
    FROM `project.dataset.orders`
    CROSS JOIN UNNEST(gifts) AS gifts
    WHERE ...+++
)
, cte as ( SELECT order_id, ...
          FROM `project.dataset.orders` t1
          join t_ids on t1.order_id=t_ids.order_id
) SELECT AVG(total_sum) AS avg_total_sum, COUNT(*) AS cnt from cte
```

your `WHERE order_id NOT IN t_ids` this line is completely wrong cause you have not select any id but used that in where clause.BTW i have changed it in by using join cause you need only common id of both table which is done by inner join

Comment: I need to run both `IN` and `NOT IN`. And the table `t_ids` have many doubles. These nuances makes hard using JOINs...

Comment: Also, I have multiple such temp tables, so using `WHERE .. IN / NOT IN ..` provides the needed flexibility. So, is it possible to make the code working this way?

Comment: @AivanF. yes possible but have to use correct syntax

Answer (score 0):

I just noticed that I can simply replace `NOT IN t_ids` with `NOT IN (SELECT order_id FROM t_ids)`:

```sql
WITH t_ids AS (
  SELECT order_id
  FROM `project.dataset.orders`
  CROSS JOIN UNNEST(gift_details) AS gift_details
  WHERE ...
)

SELECT AVG(total_sum) AS avg_total_sum, COUNT(*) AS cnt
FROM (
  SELECT order_id, ...
  FROM `project.dataset.orders`
  WHERE order_id NOT IN (SELECT order_id FROM t_ids)
)
```

Finally, the code both works and looks well! But if someone has more short & clean solution, I'll be glad to accept it.